# PHP Соседние и ближайшие цифры

Tags: php, массивы

Коллеги добрый день, сможет кто то подсказать как вывести соседние и ближайшее n - слева и справа по 3 цифры
Есть массив

```
   [0] => 11732
    [1] => 11753
    [2] => 11884
    [3] => 12019
    [4] => 12338
    [5] => 12418
```

и

```
   [0] => 11732
    [1] => 11753
    [2] => 11884
    [3] => 12000
    [4] => 12019
    [5] => 12338
    [6] => 12418
```

при поиске 12000
хотелось бы получить - получается весь указанный массив сверху, как при нахождение числа в массиве, так и без него

Answer (score 1):

Используем **[array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php)** для поиска ключа в массиве с указанным значением и если такой ключ есть делаем массиву **[unset](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unset.php)** по указанному ключу. Всё.

---

Можно применить **[array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)** для выборки только тех элементов, что не равно 12000. Правда тогда потеряется индексация и нужно переиндексировать за счёт **[array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php)**. Но то просто как вариант

Answer (score -3):

Спасибо "участникам", ответ найден

```
$allNumbers = $array;
sort($allNumbers);
$input = 12000;
$index = array_search($input, $allNumbers);
if(empty($index)){
    foreach($allNumbers as $key => $value){
        if($value < $input){
            $index = ($key + 0.5);
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
}
$below = array(
    $allNumbers[ceil($index - 2)],
    $allNumbers[ceil($index - 1)],
);

$above = array(
    $allNumbers[floor($index + 1)],
    $allNumbers[floor($index + 2)],
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array(
    "input" => $input,
    "index" => $index,
    "below" => $below,
    "above" => $above,
));
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Ага, а теперь посмотри что будет при `[11732, 11753, 11884, 12019, 12338, 12000, 12418];` и `[11732, 11753, 11884, 12019, 12000, 12338, 12418];` или `[12000, 11732, 11753, 11884, 12019, 12338, 12418]`

Comment: Array
(
    [input] => 12019
    [below] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11753
            [1] => 11884
        )

    [above] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12338
            [1] => 12418
        )

Comment: ты хоть понял что в этом коде происходит то?

Comment: @teran там есть 0.5, а это значит нужна поллитра!